# How to find probability in "exactly" situation type questions?

Tags: probability

There are two boxes, each containing two components. Each component is defective with probability $1/4$, independent of all other components. The probability that exactly one box contains exactly one defective component equals.

I did think required probability $$P=1- p\text{(no box contain no defective item)}$$
$$P= 1-\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{4}$$
But I am making some serious mistake here, that I don't know, please help out with hint. What concept of probability theory do I need to focus upon.

Comment: Defined like that $P$ is the probability that at least one box only contains non-defective components. That is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find the probability that a fixed box contains exactly one defective component. It can be component1 or component2, but not both.

> $\frac14\frac34+\frac34\frac14=\frac38$.

Then find the probability that exactly one box contains exactly one defective component. It can be box1 or box2, but not both.

> $\frac38\frac58+\frac58\frac38=\frac{15}{32}$.

Comment: I still didn't understand what's the concept is and how I can figure out such problems. Please mention where should I focus

Answer (score 0):

For a box to have exactly one bad component, you have two ways to select the bad component, a chance of $\frac 14$ the component is bad, and a chance of $\frac 34$ the other is good, so the chance is $p=2 \cdot \frac 14 \cdot \frac 34=\frac 38$  The chance that exactly one box fits this criterion is figured the same way.  Can you do that?